# RealmRecyclerViewAdapter does not work

Tags: java, android, realm, android-recyclerview

I am developing a Android App and will use Realm (this is my first App with Realm). But I have problems with my recyclerviewadapter.

I am getting an FATAL EXCEPTION

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                 Process: com.udacity.stockhawk, PID: 9880
                                                 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.udacity.stockhawk/com.udacity.stockhawk.ui.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.realm.RealmList com.udacity.stockhawk.data.Parent.getStockList()' on a null object reference
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2521)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470)
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959)
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
                                                  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'io.realm.RealmList com.udacity.stockhawk.data.Parent.getStockList()' on a null object reference
                                                     at com.udacity.stockhawk.ui.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:66)
                                                     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
                                                     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2468)
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2595) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:178) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1470) 
                                                     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
                                                     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
                                                     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5631) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:959) 
                                                     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:754)
```

My adapter is this:

```
class StockAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Stock, StockAdapter.StockViewHolder> {
    private final Context context;
    private final DecimalFormat dollarFormatWithPlus;
    private final DecimalFormat dollarFormat;
    private final DecimalFormat percentageFormat;
    private final StockAdapterOnClickHandler clickHandler;

    StockAdapter(Context context, StockAdapterOnClickHandler clickHandler,
                 OrderedRealmCollection<Stock> data) {
        super(context, data, true);
        this.context = context;
        this.clickHandler = clickHandler;

        dollarFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        dollarFormatWithPlus = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(Locale.US);
        dollarFormatWithPlus.setPositivePrefix("+$");
        percentageFormat = (DecimalFormat) NumberFormat.getPercentInstance(Locale.getDefault());
        percentageFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        percentageFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
        percentageFormat.setPositivePrefix("+");
    }

    @Override
    public StockViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View item = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item_quote, parent, false);

        return new StockViewHolder(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(StockViewHolder holder, int position) {
        final Stock stock = getItem(position);

        holder.symbol.setText(stock.getDataset_code());
        double currentPrice = stock.getQuoteHistory().first().getValue();
        double oldPrice = stock.getQuoteHistory().get(1).getValue();
        holder.price.setText(dollarFormat.format(currentPrice));
        double rawAbsoluteChange = currentPrice - oldPrice;
        double percentageChange = (rawAbsoluteChange/oldPrice) * 100.0;

        if (rawAbsoluteChange > 0) {
            holder.change.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.percent_change_pill_green);
        } else {
            holder.change.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.percent_change_pill_red);
        }

        String change = dollarFormatWithPlus.format(rawAbsoluteChange);
        String percentage = percentageFormat.format(percentageChange / 100);

        if (Utils.getDisplayMode(context)
                .equals(context.getString(R.string.pref_display_mode_absolute_key))) {
            holder.change.setText(change);
        } else {
            holder.change.setText(percentage);
        }


    }

    interface StockAdapterOnClickHandler {
        void onClick(String symbol);
    }

    class StockViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        @BindView(R.id.symbol)
        TextView symbol;

        @BindView(R.id.price)
        TextView price;

        @BindView(R.id.change)
        TextView change;

        StockViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int adapterPosition = getAdapterPosition();
            clickHandler.onClick(getItem(adapterPosition).getDataset_code());
        }
    }
}
```

And my activity onCreate code is:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        adapter = new StockAdapter(this, this, realm.where(Parent.class).findFirst().getStockList());
        stockRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        stockRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        swipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
        onRefresh();

        QuoteSyncJob.initialize(this);

        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0, ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                String symbol = adapter.getItem(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()).getDataset_code();
                Utils.removeStock(realm, symbol);
            }

        }).attachToRecyclerView(stockRecyclerView);
    }
```

What need I do to resolve this?
The other classes in the project are working.
I used this https://github.com/realm/realm-android-adapters as example

P.S.: This is for my Project 3 on Udacity Nanodegree.

Comment: Just for clarification.. your StockAdapter expecting OrderedRealmCollection< **Stock** >  but you are doing realm.where(**Parent**.class).findFirst() is it correct? I think it has to be realm.where(**Stock**.class).findFirst() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you make any changes to your Realm Objects? If you have added, deleted or chenged anything (e.g. filed type or name) you have to clear your whole database and create all objects again.

You can do this using:

```
Realm.deleteAll()
```

Comment: This shouldn't be a migration specific problem... I think this is different problem.

Comment: It might be, but as long as I work with Realm, clearing whole database is usually the easiest and the fastest sollution. At least it is first thing I do.
During development I almost always clear whole database on app start.